# Opposite verb to "inherits"

Tags: object-oriented, terminology

What's the name of the relationship opposite to "inherits"?

> Subclass inherits from superclass

> Superclass ______ subclass

Comment: I think "bequeaths to" would work from a spoken language point-of-view, I would stick to the UML terminology mentioned in the accepted answer in the context of code though.

Comment: @ChrisLee I'm not really a fan of bequeath https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425310/opposite-verb-to-inherits?noredirect=1#comment936116_425311

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In UML terminology, a subclass is said to be a specialization of a superclass.  Inversely, a superclass is a generalization of its subclass.

Comment: This is sidestepping the question, though. "to generalize" is not the opposite of "to inherit", it is the opposite of "to specialize". Also, there are languages in which specialization and inheritance are not the same thing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag indeed, generalization is the inverse of specialization, and programming languages don’t force subclassing to correspond to specialization: in theory inheritance could for example be used just for code reuse. In practice however, generalization covers the intent in most of the cases. Taking Goslin’s words e.g. in the Java white book “*Subclassing enables you to use existing code that has already been developed (...) for a more generic case*” and “*override the parts of the class you need for your specific*”. (note in the meaning that the text was written before Java generics)

Answer (score 4):

Note that a parent class cannot "do" anything with a subclass because it has no knowledge of it. The dependency relationship only goes one way.

If you insist on an active verb it would be a complex one like "passes on properties". I don't think there is a single word verb for that.

Answer (score 1):

"Parent"

Unusual, but possible to use it as a verb. You might say "is a parent of". If the are multiple levels you could use "Ancestor".

Parent/Child are commonly used alternatives to sub/super class, although you risk confusion with properties where the term is also used ie.

```
class Parent
{
    public Child Child {get;set;}
}

class Child : Parent
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Subclass and superclass are actually relationships between the two classes.

Given 2 classes "base" and "derived", the base class is a superclass of the derived class and the derived class is a subclass of the base class.

Bjarne Stroustrup in his D&E of C++ named them base and derived instead of subclass and superclass to avoid this confusion.

Comment: They are not one-word verbs (although ig you could use "superclasses")

Answer (score 0):

Just use superclass as a verb:

> B inherits from A, A superclasses B.

Answer (score -1):

This will depend highly on the programming language and the community. For example, Java uses the term "extends" rather than "inherits", therefore, since the Java community does not use the term "inherits", it also has no reason to use the opposite of "inherits".

Also, as a general rule, superclasses don't know about their subclasses, so talking about it in this direction simply does not make sense, and therefore, the question never comes up.

In English, the verb you are looking for would be "bequeath".

Comment: If we're talking about interface inheritance or subtyping (so, excluding inheritance where the primary purpose is to pull in implementation), you could say that the sperclass generalizes a subclass (or a set of them).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović "generalises" is probably the best we can get, you can make that an answer if you want to

Comment: The "Java community" certainly does use the term "inherits", even if the language uses extends.

Comment: Bequeath doesn't work at all btw. Maybe only if the entire sentence is reworked "the properties and methods are bequeathed to the subclass by the superclass", but that isn't what I'm looking for.